# how to get rid of extra values while using boost::bzip2_decompressor()

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, iostream

I have a txt file: gcc-4.7.2.txt : with the data written: Hello This is a test file. Thanks :compressed as gcc-4.7.2.tar.bz2

Now, I run the following code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/bzip2.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost::iostreams;

    char filename[] = "gcc-4.7.2.tar.bz2";

    if (!boost::filesystem::exists(filename))
    {
        cout << "Can't find " << filename << ". Expect errors to follow! " << endl;
    }

    ifstream file(filename, ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    filtering_streambuf<input> in;
    filtering_streambuf<output> out;

    in.push(bzip2_decompressor());
    in.push(file);

    try
    {
        //cout <<  "in_file:" << in << endl;
        boost::iostreams::copy(in, cout);
        //boost::iostreams::copy(in, out);
        //cout << cout << endl;
        //boost::iostreams::copy(in, compressed_string);
        //cout << "Copied" << compressed_string << "  " <<  in.str() << endl;
    }
    catch (const bzip2_error& exception)
    {
        cout << "catchblock" << endl;
        cout << exception.what() << endl;
        int error = exception.error();
        if (error == bzip2::data_error)
        {
            cout << "compressed data stream is corrupted";
        }
        else if (error == bzip2::data_error_magic)
        {
            cout << "compressed data stream does not begin with the 'magic' sequence 'B' 'Z' 'h'";
        }
        else if (error == bzip2::config_error)
        {
            cout << "libbzip2 has been improperly configured for the current platform";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error: " << error;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

While running it the output is:

dev4@sun-desktop:~/readerwriter$ ./test1 
gcc-4.7.2.txt0000644000175100001440000000004312547435102011603 0ustar  dev4usersHello 
This is a test file.

Thanks

What are the characters before Hello ? why is it printing the file name?

How to get rid of those extra values. 
and only print the content of the file:

Hello 
This is a test file.

Thanks

Comment: Don't post duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/q/31317488/85371

Comment: −1 No need to repost the question that's already been answered.

Comment: This isn't just a duplicate, it's plagiarism.

Comment: @Mysticial I assumed sock-puppets or maybe a pair of students...

Comment: sorry, is there any way to link these questions ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

These are not "extra values".

- If you don't want a tar archive, just do not use tar.

  > Instead, use `bzip2` to compress the single file
- If the input is a tar archive, extract with `tar`.

  > Boost does **not** support tar archives

Comment: okay so I compressed using bzip2 hello.txt ; It becomes hello.txt.bz2. Now when I use the above code, it doesn't print extra values (I understand that this is content of the file); is there no command while running ./test1 ; it removes this starting values. something like " ./test1 | tar -x " this command just doesn't print anything. Also how can I remove the 'cout' stream from the copy(in, cout) codeline and make my own writing stream such as copy(in,abc) and whenever I want to print the content or read the content I use the cout << abc ? something like this ?Any help weill be appreciated.

Comment: yes. Those are just filenames. Change them with e.g. `mv hello.txt.bz2 i_prefer_little_ponies.magic.bin` or, indeed: `bzip2 hello.txt > my_filename.wow`